# Horizontal scrolling of page not working within div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this plugin here for horizontal scrolling.
http://manos.malihu.gr/horizontal-page-animation-to-id-with-jquery/

Here is the demo link I have created using it. http://aijaz.co/hearing1/

The problem I am facing is, I can scroll the pages when the link to scroll is just below .content. When I put the link in several divs, the page doesn't scroll. Example:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <hr />
        <a href="#top">&larr; Back to start</a> <a href="#" rel="next">Next section &rarr;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script it is using.

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $(window).load(function() {

            /* Page Scroll to id fn call */
            $("#navigation-menu a,a[href='#top'],a[rel='m_PageScroll2id']").mPageScroll2id({
                layout: "horizontal",
                highlightSelector: "#navigation-menu a"
            });

            /* demo functions */
            $("a[rel='next']").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var to = $(this).parent().parent("section").next().attr("id");
                $.mPageScroll2id("scrollTo", to);
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) up through the clicked element's ancestors instead of using `.parent()` multiple times:

```
$("a[rel='next']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var to=$(this).closest("section").next().attr("id");
    $.mPageScroll2id("scrollTo",to);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong i guess, Use same class for every tag and try sure it will work , go through plugin document .

Comment: Thanks Srikanth. But, I am not using any class at all.

Comment: I am saying to use same class